# Entity Framework, Foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I use Entity Code first for my project. Basically I have 3 class `Users`,`Branchs` and `UsersBranchs`.

`Users` contains `UserID`, `Name` ,...

`Branchs` contains `BranchID`, `Location`, ...  and UserID which is refer to creator of branch
and `UsersBranchs` just have have two column BranchID and UserID which is define which user is in which branch

the problem is I get this error:

> 'FK_dbo.UsersBranchs_dbo.Users_UsersID' on table 'UsersBranchs' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Can you help me please?

**Update**

It's UsersBranchs Class

```
[ForeignKey("UserID")]
public CoreUsers User { get; set; }
public Guid UsersID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("BranchID")]
public Branchs Branch { get; set; }
public Guid BranchID { get; set; }
```

And also add this line to DbContext class to use both UserID and BranchID as key

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UsersBranchs>().HasKey(x => new { x.UserID, x.BranchID });
```

Branchs Class is

```
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Key]
   public Guid ID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("UserID")]
   public CoreUsers User { get; set; }
   public Guid UserID { get; set; }

   public .....
```

Users Class is

```
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Key]
   public Guid ID { get; set; }

   public .....
```

Comment: Are you getting this message on SQL server?

Comment: You should show the PK & FK settings too.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found a solution, please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613117/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being able to [handle multiple cascade paths](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/307723/allow-multiple-cascade-paths-for-foreign-key-and-on-dalete-update-cascade) and [cascade delete to same table](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/470632/foreign-key-that-references-the-same-table) has been a limitation of Sql Server for a long time. Just Google the error message. Basically, if you want to use cascade delete then you'll have to make sure that there is only a single cascade path.

At the moment you have two paths from Branchs -> UsersBranchs and Branchs -> Users -> UsersBranchs.

EF by default sets cascade delete but it may be stopped by removing the conventions in your DbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Manually set cascade delete behaviour
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Then you'll have to set WillCascadeOnDelete(true) on any relationships where you want cascade delete. See the [Entity Framework documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete).

Other than that your model seems a bit strange. You look like you're trying to make a many-to-many link/join table, UsersBranchs, but you also have a single User on the Branchs which doesn't really make sense. Do you even need the UsersBranchs table in that case? Did you mean to have a collection of Users on your Branchs, i.e. a navigation property rather than a foreign key, which gives a one-to-many relationship Branchs -> Users?

As an aside I really dislike using plurals for single entities.

Comment: I use user in branchs class (table) to track to find who create that Branch and the other many to many (UsersBranchs) to find members of the branchs. does it make scenes? 
In other hand I often make IsDeleted flag to track deleted records and keep them in database.
Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the problem because you didn't tell Entity framework how it will treat these classes on delete on cascade

in your DbContext class, override the OnModelCreating method and write this code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
     modelBuilder.Entity<UserBranch>()
         .HasRequired(t => t.CoreUsers)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserID)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

     modelBuilder.Entity<UserBranch>()
         .HasRequired(t => t.Branch)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(t => t.BranchID)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>()
         .HasRequired(t => t.User)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserID)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: @Ostad, you are welcome, how you solved it? using my answer? if yes, please mark it as answer and vote, thank you in advance